# QGIS Raster Convert Negative Values to NULL

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, convert, null

I have a DEM layer in QGIS and want to replace all cells with negative values to the value "NULL". How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use raster calculator and warp:

Reclassify raster values below 0 to some value, I use -99.

```
("yourrastername@1"<0)*-99 + ("yourrastername@1">=0)*"yourrastername@1"
```

Which means "if the value is below 0 then: 1 * -99 + 1 * your raster value".

[image]

Then set values of -99 to no data using Warp:

[image]